# Xcode 4.4 Memory (Core Foundation/Objective-C) Potential leak of an object stored into 'navcontrol'

Tags: xcode, xcode4

I am new to Xcode, and iI would really appreciate any help in eliminating this memory leak.
 It shows up on the line: 
        [window addSubview:navcontrol.view];
Below is my code:

```
#import "ExSignupAppDelegate.h"
#import "SignupTableViewController.h"

@implementation ExSignupAppDelegate

@synthesize window;

@synthesize viewController;

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
    {
    UINavigationController* navcontrol;
    navcontrol = [[UINavigationController alloc]init];
    SignupTableViewController* signupVC = [[SignupTableViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"SignupTableViewController" bundle:nil];
    signupVC.title = NSLocalizedString(@"Title Abstract Search", @"");
    [navcontrol pushViewController:signupVC animated:NO];
    [signupVC release];
    [window addSubview:navcontrol.view];

    return YES;
    }

-(void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application
{
    [window addSubview:viewController.view];
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];
}

- (void)dealloc
{

    [window release];
    [viewController release];
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1):

You're creating navController using alloc/init, so you are responsible for releasing it.
Change your line

```
navController = [[UINavigationController alloc]init];
```

to

```
navController = [[[UINavigationController alloc]init] autorelease];
```

This throws your navController to the autoreleasepool where it is released later. If you need navController in other methods you should store it in a property.

Comment: It gives me the error `ARC forbids explicit message send of 'autorelease'`

Answer (score 0):

```
[window addSubview:navcontrol.view];
```

should be replaced as

```
window.rootViewController = navcontrol;
```